# Iframe youtube video in phonegap/cordova on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, youtube, phonegap

I have read a lot of answers about this problem but I haven't found a solution.
I'm testing an *hybrid app* on **android** and **iOS** with **phonegap** and **cordova**.
I have insert an iframe of youtube like this:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CODE?feature=player_embedded" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

On android works perfectly but on iOS I see only the space of video and not the video.
I have add the *white list plugin*.
In the top of the page I have add:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src * data:'unsafe-inline'">
```

and in the *config.xml*:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

I have tried a lot of things but none works for me.
Is it a problem of phonegap or cordova? If I create an ipa, is the problem resolved? Am I doing something wrong? Or am I forgetting something?
Thank you so much

Comment: Do you have <allow-navigation href="https://*youtube.com/*"/> as well in your config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found the solution and I hope it can help.
In the **config.xml** I added the string `<allow-navigation href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/*"/>` inside the code

```
<platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

So the final result is:

```
<platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <allow-navigation href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/*"/>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

in config.xml